# Laravel query writing

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5

I am developing a project in Laravel 5.4. I want to write a select, insert and update query in my model that should work for any table in database. I used to do this is Codeigniter and work fine there, but I don't know how to use it in Laravel.

Following is the code from a model file in Codeigniter

```
class General_Model extends CI_Model {

        public function fetch_CoustomQuery($sql){
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        return $query->result(); 

        }


        public function create_record($data, $tbl) 
        {
        $this->db->set($data);
        $this->db->insert($tbl);
        return ($this->db->affected_rows() != 1) ? FALSE : TRUE;
        }



        public function update_record($data, $tbl, $wher) 
        {
        $this->db->where($wher);
        $this->db->set($data);
        $this->db->update($tbl);
        }


        public function delete_record($tbl, $wher) 
        {
        $this->db->where($wher);
        $this->db->delete($tbl);         
        } 
}
```

It was very easy in Codeigniter. I only need to pass the parameters and worked fine. I want to write same queries in my model in Laravel. Please help

Comment: In Laravel, this would usually go in the controller, not the model. Take a look at [Laravel's Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries).

Comment: "I want to write a select, insert and update query in my model that should work for any table in database." No, you don't. You want to use the built-in functionality instead of creating an additional weird ORM on top of the existing, well thought-out ORM.

Comment: Additionally, I strongly recommend subscribing to Laracasts. Specifically, [here is a screencast based on the query builder](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/8?autoplay=true) - (Link updated)

Answer (score 3):

I would **strongly** recommend reading the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries) but the methods are as simple as:

```
GeneralModel::create(["num" => 1, "name" => 2]);
GeneralModel::where("num", ">", 2)->update(["num" => 1]);
GeneralModel::where("num", ">", 2)->delete();
```

There is no need to put these methods on the models.

Answer (score 1):

if you really want something like that then you can have function there that accepts models as parameter:

```
public function create_record($model,$data)
{
    $model::create($data);
}
```

where in the controller you can do something like

```
$model = App\Fruit; // lets say fruit is a model you have
GeneralModel::create_record($model,$data);
```

but why not just go straight with it like:

```
$var = App\Fruit::create($data);
```

this is redundant .. for each model have a way to fetch , insert , update or delete records from their perspective table .. i suggest you read more documentation about [Laravel Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent)